# How to detect mouse wheel scrolling in flutter web?

Tags: flutter-web

How can you detect mouse wheel scroll in flutter web?  It seems like it would be in a gesture detector but I don't see it in there. How do list views detect mouse scroll?

Answer (score 19):

Wrap your `ListView` (or any other scroll view) with [Listener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html) and listen for [PointerScrollEvent](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/PointerScrollEvent-class.html):

```dart
Listener(
  onPointerSignal: (pointerSignal){
    if(pointerSignal is PointerScrollEvent){
      // do something when scrolled
      print('Scrolled');
    }
  },
  child: ... //your scrollview here
)
```